# Autocompletion for multiple js files in Cloud9

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, cloud9-ide, ace-editor

I'm trying to move my workspace to c9 because the Ace editor's autocompletion really pleased me when I worked on NodeJS projects.

But now I would like to work on JS files client-sided. It is from this point autocompletion going wrong. Indeed, there is nothing such as "require" command in client-side JS inside of the JS files themselves (except using some plugins) to inform of the other source files used in.

So when I use, in one of my JS files, a function that is defined in an other file (even libraries, frameworks : jquery, etc), Ace notifies me that the function is not defined (cause it has no way to know that the function is defined in another file, I guess).

Here we go : is there some comment line I could put in my code, or some configuration of c9 I could set, to correct that behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the errors and warning, you can just add the following line near the top of your javascript file:

`/* globals jquery lodash someOtherLibrary */`

However, Cloud9 doesn't do autocomplete for client side libraries yet.

Comment: Okay, this is the best answer I could expect, I think. Thank !

Answer (score 1):

## Abuse C9's require support

When you use `var yourLibrary = require("./somefile.js");`, auto-completion works perfectly.

But, as you stated, `require()` doesn't exist, nor do you want to have `yourLibrary` set to undefined. (Or to just throw an error)

**As it turns out, C9 isn't that smart:**

```
//Your library was defined in some other file

var yourLibrary; //"This does nothing other than making C9 happy
function require() {return 1;} //Define the require function
if(false) {
   yourLibrary = require("yourLibraryFile.js");
}
```

Now, you can use autocomplete (it even shows the documentation comments)!

Note: It doesn't always work.